# Reverse triangle inequality proof checking

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, triangle-inequality

I have seen other proofs of the inequality, but I haven’t seen the one I found. I would like to know if it’s correct, and what I could improve. Here’s the proof:

First we prove $(\lvert a\rvert - \lvert b\rvert)^2 \leq (a-b)^2 $, where $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$.

$$
\begin{align}
(\lvert a\rvert - \lvert b\rvert)^2 &= \lvert a \rvert^2 - 2 \lvert a\rvert \lvert b\rvert + \lvert b\rvert^2 \\
&= a^2 - \lvert 2ab\rvert + b^2 \\
&\leq a^2 - 2ab + b^2 \\
&= (a-b)^2 \\
\Rightarrow\sqrt(\lvert a\rvert -\lvert b\rvert)^2 &= \lvert \lvert a \rvert - \lvert b\rvert\rvert \\
&\leq \sqrt(a-b)^2 \\
&= \lvert a - b\rvert 
\end{align}$$

Thus $\lvert \lvert a \rvert - \lvert b\rvert \rvert \leq \lvert a - b\rvert \ \forall a, b \in \mathbb{R}.$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. That is a nice question, but note that the [tag:proof-writing] tag is inappropriate for it.

Comment: And, yes, the proof is correct.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, José!